# All jQuery has simply stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing something quite frustrating. All of the jQuery I'm using on my site has stopped working entirely. Here's exactly what happened.

This morning, everything was working just as it should. I have all of my jQuery in an external scripts.js file, and I went to simply add something to one of my statements:

```
$(function() {
    if (location.pathname == "/shoppingcart.asp")
     || location.pathname == "/ShoppingCart.asp") {
          $('.v65-cart-tax-row').css("display", "none"); <!-- tax hide -->
          $('#v65-cart-empty-details-cell').before($('.v65-cart-total-estimate-row')); <!-- fix total price location -->
          $('#v65-cart-shipping-details-container').css("display", "none"); <!-- hide calculate shipping box -->
       }
    }
});
```

I simply added one more css alteration to the if statement, and saved the file, but when I reloaded my site, NONE of the rules were being applied to the targeted page (/shoppingcart.asp). Keep in mind that all of my other jQuery scripts were on this same page, and they were all still working.

So I tried moving this script into it's own script tag in the HTML file, but that still wasn't working. So then I tried to test something. I removed the link to the scripts.js file that has all my jQuery, and saved the file. Then, I simply pasted the link back into the file just as it was, saved it, and now NONE of it is working!

After researching a little bit, I found that usually when jQuery stops working, its because the link to the jQuery file stopped being valid if they update it or something. But the eCommerce platform im using provides the links for us, which are //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js and //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js, and they still seem to be working just fine. Plus, it still doesn't explain why they only stopped working AFTER I edited them.

What's even worse is that a script they provided:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
jQuery('#breadcrumb').closest('td').remove(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Is still working just fine, even after I removed it and put it back in.

Does anyone have any help or suggestions?? I have no idea what to do, and feel completely defeated by this. An entire summer's worth of work has just gone away in the blink of an eye.

Comment: [JSHint Code Quality Tool](http://www.jshint.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Surely you've got your developer console open so that you can see JavaScript syntax and runtime errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
if (location.pathname == "/shoppingcart.asp")
 || location.pathname == "/ShoppingCart.asp") {
```

Should be:

```
if (location.pathname == "/shoppingcart.asp"
 || location.pathname == "/ShoppingCart.asp") {
```

**And** you have an extra `}` at the end.

Javascript syntax errors can break the whole darn thing. Be sure to check your javascript console in the future, and use a tool like jshint or jslint.

Comment: Well... this is embarrassing. I was so sure I had checked thoroughly for syntax errors. I don't know how that extra curly brace got in there, but that was indeed the problem. If you'll excuse me, I have a hole of shame to curl up in.

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes. Just be sure to check your javascript error console next time.